# Why Querydsl always requires connection to be transactional?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, querydsl

Recently I tried a new tool for db access called Querydsl in my Spring Boot app, here is how I configure the context in `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public com.querydsl.sql.Configuration querydslConfiguration() {
    SQLTemplates templates = OracleTemplates.builder().build();
    com.querydsl.sql.Configuration configuration = new com.querydsl.sql.Configuration(templates);
    configuration.setExceptionTranslator(new SpringExceptionTranslator());
    return configuration;
}

@Bean
public SQLQueryFactory queryFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    Provider<Connection> provider = new SpringConnectionProvider(dataSource);
    return new SQLQueryFactory(querydslConfiguration(), provider);
}
```

My query is a quite simple select:

```
fun detailedEntityByIds(ids: Set<String>): List<DetailedEntity> {
    val qDetails = QTContainerDetails.tContainerDetails
    return sqlQueryFactory.select(qDetails).from(qDetails)
        .where(qDetails.id.`in`(ids))
        .fetch().map { mapper.qDslEntToModel(it) }
}
```

Then I faced with was the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not transactional

I quickly found this question: [[QueryDSL/Spring]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34198920/3581539) with an advice to use `@Transactional` for solving this problem.

Why does Querydsl requires connections to be transactional? I used to put `@Transactional` on a service layer methods where I really need it. Now Querydsl 'forces' me to put it on a whole DAO class, because looks like it is required for every Querydsl query.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc

```
/**
 * {@code SpringConnectionProvider} is a Provider implementation which provides a transactionally bound connection
 *
 * <p>Usage example</p>
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * Provider<Connection> provider = new SpringConnectionProvider(dataSource());
 * SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = SQLQueryFactory(configuration, provider);
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
```

The reason is for resource management. You don't have access to the underlying JDBC implementation. The transaction will close ResultSets, Statements, Connections, etc. Without a transaction, every connection would be left open, the connection pool saturated, the database running out of resources, etc.

If you want to manage your own resources, you could write your own `Provider<Connection>` and pass in the `DataSource` E.G.

```
private static Provider<Connection> getConnection(DataSource dataSource) {
    return () -> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
}
```